# How do Function and Sub work in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

If I have a function and it does not return a value, is it converted to sub when compiled?

Comment: No. You can treat `functions` as `subs` in Basic. Furthermore the `call` statement explicitly treats functions as subs.

Comment: For a function called `Dog()` that doesn't assign a return value `Msgbox IsEmpty(Dog())` will return true.